# .NET Language Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, culture

I'm trying to set language using .NET MVC Web Application

Here is my SetCulture function;

```
        public ActionResult SetCulture( string lan ) {
        string Culture = Request.QueryString.Get( "lan" );

        // Validate input
        Culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture( Culture );
        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[ "_culture" ];
        if ( cookie != null )
            cookie.Value = Culture;   // update cookie value
        else {
            cookie = new HttpCookie( "_culture" );
            cookie.Value = Culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears( 1 );
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add( cookie );
        //Session["_culture"] = Culture;
        return RedirectToAction( "../Home/Index" );
    }
```

Here is the first problem;
When the page `http://localhost:55616/Home/Index` is open, it is okay to change language.
However, when `http://localhost:55616` is open, it refresh automatically, but not change language.

Here is the second problem;
As can be seen, I'm redirecting the page to the `../Home/Index` page. But I need to redirect to page to itself, for example, when it is on `../Home/UserSettings`, it would be `../Home/UserSettings` after changing the language.

Comment: first problem you can step debug to see what's different between two url the second problem you may need a parameter as returnUrl that you can Redirect to after changing the language

Comment: Do you have an idea to get on which page language change request is sent ?

Comment: you can pass a parameter to show the page which sent the language change request

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
public ActionResult SetCulture( string lan ) {
        string Culture = Request.QueryString.Get( "lan" );
        var returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
        // Validate input
        Culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture( Culture );
        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[ "_culture" ];
        if ( cookie != null )
            cookie.Value = Culture;   // update cookie value
        else {
            cookie = new HttpCookie( "_culture" );
            cookie.Value = Culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears( 1 );
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add( cookie );
        //Session["_culture"] = Culture;
        return Redirect( returnUrl.OriginalString );
    }
```

Request.UrlReferrer; returns the page where the request is sent.